# Least Recently Used and Least Frequently Used Page Replacement Algorithm

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a Page Replacement Solver that will display a visualization of the algorithm. It gives me the correct number of page faults and page hits, however, in the output visualization it doesn't display the right paging in the frames. Can someone help me with this problem? I fixed this problem in the First In First Out algorithm but in the Least Recently Used LRU and Least Frequently Used LFU, I don't know.

```
    if (policy === "fifo") {
        //* Store 'FIFO' as a value for the algorithmName, this will be displayed in the result
        algorithmName = "FIFO";
    
        let oldestPageIndex = 0; // Track the index of the oldest page in the page table
    
        //* Iterate through the array of pages
        for (let i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
            let page = parseInt(pages[i]);
    
            //* Check if the current page is already in the page table
            //* If the current page is already in the page table, page hit will be incremented
            //* If not, page fault will be incremented
            if (pageTable.includes(page)) {
                pageHits++;
                pageFaultCounter.push(0);
            } else {
                pageFaults++;
                pageFaultCounter.push(1);
    
                //* If all frames are occupied, remove the oldest page from the page table
                if (pageTable.length === numFrames) {
                    pageTable[oldestPageIndex] = page; // Replace the oldest page with the new page
                    oldestPageIndex = (oldestPageIndex + 1) % numFrames; // Update the    oldestPageIndex
                } else {
                    pageTable.push(page); // Insert the new page into the page table
                }
            }
    
            //* Object for the references and frames
            let row = {
                reference: page,
                //* Store the array of pages as a String concatenated with a line break
                frames: pageTable.join("<br><hr>"),
                faults: pageFaultCounter,
            };
            //* Push the row object to the tableData array
            tableData.push(row);
        }
    }
    
    // TODO: LRU code
    else if (policy === "lru") {
        algorithmName = "LRU";
        for (let i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
            let page = parseInt(pages[i]);
    
            if (pageTable.includes(page)) {
                // Page hit
                pageHits++;
                pageFaultCounter.push(0);
    
                // Update the page's position in the pageTable
                const pageIndex = pageTable.indexOf(page);
                pageTable.splice(pageIndex, 1);
                pageTable.push(page);
            } else {
                // Page fault
                pageFaults++;
                pageFaultCounter.push(1);
    
                if (pageTable.length === numFrames) {
                    // Remove the least recently used page
                    pageTable.shift();
                }
    
                // Add the new page to the pageTable
                pageTable.push(page);
            }
    
            let row = {
                reference: page,
                frames: pageTable.join("<br><hr>"),
            };
    
            tableData.push(row);
        }
    }
    
    // TODO: LFU code
    else {
        algorithmName = "LFU";
    
        const pageFrequency = new Map();
    
        for (let i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
            let page = parseInt(pages[i]);
    
            if (pageTable.includes(page)) {
                // Page hit
                pageHits++;
                pageFaultCounter.push(0);
    
                // Increment the page's frequency
                pageFrequency.set(page, (pageFrequency.get(page) || 0) + 1);
            } else {
                // Page fault
                pageFaults++;
                pageFaultCounter.push(1);
    
                if (pageTable.length === numFrames) {
                    // Find the page with the minimum frequency
                    let minFrequencyPage = pageTable[0];
                    let minFrequency =
                        pageFrequency.get(minFrequencyPage) || Infinity;
    
                    for (let j = 1; j < pageTable.length; j++) {
                        const currentPage = pageTable[j];
                        const currentFrequency =
                            pageFrequency.get(currentPage) || Infinity;
    
                        if (currentFrequency < minFrequency) {
                            minFrequencyPage = currentPage;
                            minFrequency = currentFrequency;
                        }
                    }
    
                    // Remove the page with the minimum frequency
                    const pageIndex = pageTable.indexOf(minFrequencyPage);
                    pageTable.splice(pageIndex, 1);
                    pageFrequency.delete(minFrequencyPage);
                }
    
                // Add the new page to the pageTable
                pageTable.push(page);
                pageFrequency.set(page, 1);
            }
    
            let row = {
                reference: page,
                frames: pageTable.join("<br><hr>"),
            };
    
            tableData.push(row);
        }
    }
```

Note: The above code for the logic and the code below is the output visualization of the algorithm.

output = '

### Summary - ${algorithmName} Algorithm

```
    <ul class="pl-4 font-regular">
      <li class="list-disc py-px"><strong>Algorithm:</strong> ${algorithmName}</li>
      <li class="list-disc py-px"><strong>Pages:</strong> ${stream}</li>
      <li class="list-disc py-px"><strong>Reference Stream:</strong> ${pages.join(
          ", "
      )}</li>
    </ul>
    <h2 class="text-xl font-bold pt-4">Solution Visualization</h2>
    <table class="w-full bg-myGray my-8">
    
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th class="border text-center py-4 w-2/12">Reference</th>
    
        ${tableData
    
            .map(
                (row) => '
                
                <td class="border text-center py-4 font-bold">${row.reference}</td>
            
        '
            )
            .join("")}
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <th class="border text-center py-4 w-2/12">Frames</th>
    
        ${tableData
            .map(
                (row) => '
                
                <td class="border text-center align-top py-4">
                
                        ${row.frames}
                    
                </td>
            
        '
            )
            .join("")}
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <th class="border text-center py-4 w-2/12">Hit</th>
    

        
        
            ${pageFaultCounter.map((value) =>
                value === 1
                    ? '<td class="border text-center align-top py-4 bg-red-500 font-semibold text-white">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
                    </td>'
                    : '<td class="border text-center align-top py-4 bg-green-500 font-semibold text-white">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i>
                    </td>'
            )}

    <ul class="pl-4 font-regular">
      <li class="list-disc py-px"><strong>Total Page Hit:</strong> ${pageHits}</li>
      <li class="list-disc py-px"><strong>Total Page Fault:</strong> ${pageFaults}</li>
      <li class="list-disc py-px"><strong>Hit Rate:</strong> ${pageHits} / ${
        pages.length
    } = ${pageHitRatio.toFixed(2)}%</li>
      <li class="list-disc"><strong>Fault Rate:</strong> ${pageFaults} / ${
        pages.length
    } = ${pageFaultRatio.toFixed(2)}%</li>
    </ul>
```

';